# Powershell - Can't get export-csv to work with Where-Object CreatedDate

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to Export-Csv with the following PS code but when I open the generated .csv file, all I get is: "ï»¿". This has obviously something to do with the encoding and BOM I reccon, but whatever I try it wont work.

```
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$searchroot = "Example OU"

#GetADUsers
Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $searchroot -Enabled -SizeLimit 0 | Select 
UserPrincipalName,whenCreated | Where-Object {$_.CreatedDateTime -ge $Date} |
Export-Csv -Path 'ExamplePath.csv' -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8
```

I tried adding -NoTypeInformation, removed -Delimiter, changed -Encoding. Nothing seems to be correct. If I remove `Where-Object {$_.CreatedDateTime -ge $Date}` it works just fine.

I might just be missing something very obvious here.

Thanks!
//Victor

Comment: Note the different property names `whenCreated` & `CreatedDateTime`.

Comment: Sheesh, alright so I'm just stupid as per usual. Thanks @notjustme

Comment: @notjustme Please vote to close as "caused by typo".